# How do I sort documents by Mongo based on one criterion?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model in Mongoose

```
Store:{
    name: <String>,
    regionName: <String>,
    coordinates: CoordinatesSchema
    }

CoordinatesSchema :{
longitude: <Number>
latitude: <Number>
}
```

I want to search the database by giving my own coordinates (mylatitude, my longitude) for the 4 nearest stores, sorting them from the nearest to the farthest (the distance is considered to be the Cartesian distance of two points-sqrt((mylongitude-longtude)^2 +(mylatitude-latitude)^2). Is there a way to place an auxiliary function in the model so that it is returns to me the documents with a command like Store.find({something}) or do I have to take all documents of the database and do it with a function outside?

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-sort) you can sort in this way

```js
yourModel.find({}).sort('yourSort').then(result => {console.log(result)})
```

You can use multiple ways. As explained into docs, for example `sort({ field: 'asc', test: -1 })` is the same as `sort('field -test')`